# Ejecting to bare expo can't install on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently had to switch to the bare workflow from the managed workflow. After running expo eject I tested on android, which suffered from an issue with expo-constants not being available, after installing that it worked just fine. I moved on to installing it on the iOS simulator and got an error trying to install. Been trying to debug it but not having any luck. Logs are below:

```
success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-dtoeptcccdubmbcvblrjlzhwexaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/***.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Could not install at this time.
Failed to chmod /Users/***/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8666E576-E2C9-4711-B8EB-2A7720C08B84/data/Bundle/Application/F519E6C9-3AFC-49F4-B0E5-9D40C41F54D6/***.app/*** : No such file or directory
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
    Failed to chmod /Users/pedromcunha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8666E576-E2C9-4711-B8EB-2A7720C08B84/data/Bundle/Application/F519E6C9-3AFC-49F4-B0E5-9D40C41F54D6/***.app/*** : No such file or directory
info Launching "com.***.***"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "com.***.***" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "com.***.***" is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.***.***" is unknown to FrontBoard.
    Application "com.***.***" is unknown to FrontBoard.
```

I redacted any sensitive info with ***. It says that the build was successful but after looking into the build itself I don't see any executable. Here's the folder contents of the .app package.

[image: 1]

Any help is much appreciated.